# Database in Visual Studio's solution

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2005, ado.net

Why does Visual Studio asks (Optionally) to add database .mdf file to be stored in project output folder? It's still is a requirement that .mdf file to be part of running SQL Server instance so that application can work with the database.
For instance if I stop the instance of SQL Server and run the application, it throws exceptions etc. I wonder why it stays in VS solution folders then? Any advantage of this?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is generally to allow for the "User Instance" feature, which lets you make a copy of the MDF file for local debugging purposes (without impacting the database that's running within SQL Server).

You can see [this URL for more information on how this feature works](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143684.aspx), but I would just ignore it, since it is deprecated and in SQL Server 2012 is replaced with [a fundamentally better and different way of dealing with isolation and avoiding instance maintenance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh510202%28SQL.110%29.aspx) (no more `AttachDbFileName` nonsense).

Personally, I think it's much better to work with a single copy of the database, attached to a proper instance of SQL Server, because these other methods just seem far too convoluted and confusing for very little gain. But maybe that's just me.